# Wordpress: Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted - but increase the limit doesn't work

Tags: php, wordpress, memory

Today I wake up and my website is not working. Other server sites work fine, but they don’t use Wordpess. I have not modified configurations, permissions or plugins, nor have I made any updates. Yesterday I uploaded content and everything was working perfectly.

So, I get this message:

**Fatal error**: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in **/var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wpdb.php** on line **1793**

**Fatal error**: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in **/var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-fatal-error-handler.php** on line **74**

So, I did the following:
I put this line in wp-config:

`define( ‘WP_MEMORY_LIMIT’, ‘256M’` );
I modified the php.ini file like this:

`memory_limit = 256M`
I edited the .htaccess file like this:

`php_value memory_limit 256M`

(in the last line before #END WordPress) EDIT: Also try put that after <php? . Doesn't work.

But doesn’t work. Actually, I see the same message.

Answer (score -2):

Add the line ini_set('memory_limit', '-1'); to your wp-config.php file.

Comment: Done. But doesn't work. I got the same message.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. If setting the limit to other values does not work, why should setting it to `-1` resolve the problem?